# Bootstrap 4 CSS – Overriding default caption-side:bottom not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I'm using Bootstrap and trying to move my table captions back to the top of my tables, and I meeting with strange resistance.

The style wins as far specificity, as seen in the developer inspector. And yet, the caption stubbornly remains beneath the table... mocking me.

When I first added the caption-side style, it worked fine. At some point after adding a bit content and further styles to the table, it no longer did. Now I've stripped things back to the barest elements, but that caption will not budge.

Why on earth would the inspector show "caption-side:top;" while the display disagrees and slaps it at the bottom?

Here's a simple pen illustrating the issue. Hoping this is a slam dunk for someone, 'cause I'm flummoxed.

All the CSS:

```
.crtable{
caption-side: top;
}
```

https://codepen.io/halfacre/pen/KJBJqZ

Comment: Note that you can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to share your code here on Stack Overflow rather than only on an external site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to implement `caption-side` style to `caption`.

(https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PVBLBB)

CSS

```
caption{
  color:red;
    caption-side: top;
}
```

Comment: Well that seems pretty intuitive, doesn't it? Y'know, I swear it worked on table...! For a minute...? If not for that, I might have eventually tried this. Problem solved. Thanks, Dmitry.

Answer (score 0):

Double check your table's markup. If any of your `<td>`, `<tr>`, or `<th>` tags are out of line with `<table>` standard markup then it may be causing this error. At least that was the case for me!